# My device is busy: Copying Symbol Files in Xcode 6.4

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

[image]

I am getting this warning, when I try to run app in my device. Kindly guide me how to solve this. I am trying fro past two days. I unable to do. **Copying Symbol Files** is in status bar. Progress view also not get loaded. I referred some answers in stack overflow. But, not yet solved.  I dont know what to do? Kindly guide me.

**Device Worked in my iMAC:**

Xcode Version 6.3
iOS Version 8.2

**Same Device for another MAC BOOK PRO:**

Device not worked with another MAC BOOK PRO. So following steps we followed.

**1**. OS Upgraded to 8.3, and same day, that device connected to another MAC Book Pro, by creating New Certificates as per procedure.

**2**. received error like, **Version not supported XCode**

**3**. So we upgraded Xcode to 6.4, iOS 8.3, working successfully in another MAC.

**4**. Now, in my iMAC, version updated to XCode 6.4 and iOS version 8.3.

From that day onwards, if I try to run in device, I unable to run. **Copying symbol files** error only receiving. But working in MAC BOOk PRO.

Kindly help me. How to solve this?

Comment: Wait until copying symbol files is done.

Comment: I couldn run any other app too. If u know any idea, just help me.

Comment: you have to wait until all symbol files copy from the device

Comment: I think they mean it's not getting past that point. Same thing is happening to me. I've tried rebooting, waiting 30 minutes, closing things, replugging it in. It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Same here with Xcode 7.

Comment: We have to wait @leanne . I have waited for a week. U can try with another device. It may connect. Bcos, here,, iPhone made that trouble. but, iPAD not made any trouble.

Comment: Yeah, I waited - and waited - and waited. (I was only having the problem on one computer, though.) What finally fixed it was reinstalling iTunes, of all things. It seems that Xcode and iTunes both use a file called AppleUSBEthernetHost.kext. If that file gets corrupted, it can cause this issue as well as issues using hotspot USB tethering from iPhone. Fixing that file fixed both issues for me. See [How to fix iTunes 10.6 iPhone's USB Personal Hotspot problem | Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3787866)

Answer (score 14):

Tried all the above and failed.
The solution that worked for me turned out to be as simple as going to Settings > Developer > Clear Trusted devices.
I then reconnected my device at which point it prompted me to trust the computer on my phone.
I then went to finder , selected the device and click on the trust button. It copied cache and completed the whole process in less than 2 seconds. After spending 3 hours waiting for it to finish caching.

Comment: Hi,  You can upvote this question too. Bcos, I will be useful for SO followers.

Comment: For others which are as clueless as me, the developer option is NOT in General. Its a bit down in the list. (For me, it's just before the list of all the installed apps)

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait a while (about 4 minutes).
Some projects take a long time to build

Comment: Two ways:
**1)** about 4 mins, or about 40 mins, we have to wait until this over. 
**2)** We have to uninstall xcode and reinstall.

Comment: It did worked after 2 minutes of loading for me, I was scared

Answer (score 2):

What I did to fix this:

1. Delete app while still connected to mac.
2. Close Xcode
3. Right click on the Xcode app icon on mac screen, and select quit.
4. Unplug iPhone
5. Reopen the Xcode project.
6. Connect iPhone
7. Select whatever you are using
8. Hit start.

It should work. I am currently in Xcode 8 (Swift 3), and this fixed my problem in a minute. 
I hope that this solution works for you.

Good Luck,
Pranav :)